# How can I Replace a column value with another column value in a existed output copied from record set preset in a remote data base through sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

Ok example:

I have a table named `Item` on remote data base. Item have these columns `Part Number`, `Description`, `Vendor name`, and `Vendor Part Number`.

I have extracted values in the columns through this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Part Number ='123' 

Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset
```

and result is :

```
123   Ball   Walmart   192-3
```

Now I have new column in table `Item` named `Manufacture`.

What I want is on the same existing extracted copy I want to replace values of `Vendor Name` with `Manufacture`, so that the result will be like this.

```
123 Ball Addidas 192-3
```

Value of `Vendor Name` will be replaced by value of `Manufacture`.

What query should be should ? I am new to Sql.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT `Part Number`, `Description`, `Manufacture`, `Vendor Part Number`. 
FROM Item WHERE `Part Number` ='123' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Item SET Vendor_Name = Manufacture WHERE Part_Number ='123'
```